# iOS build time error Asset.xcasset No such file or directory

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcasset

I'm getting an error while trying to run the app on the simulator, using Xcode 12.4

/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CCBC-
exyindmimlkaxncxdeubzcgqxqgc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CCBC.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CCBC.build/Script-7DBCCAD36C20635EF76D902C.sh: line 4: /Users/apple/Desktop/MyProjects/CCBC_iOS/CCBC.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/.xcassets/Asset.xcasset: No such file or directory

When I select the Asset.xcasset from files in Xcode it shows the file path as /CCBC_iOS/CCBC/Asset.xcasset

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try clearing the derived data, clean the project and build again

Comment: Have you insured that the xcassets folder has the proper target membership?

Comment: Try to rename with this **Assets.xcassets** and clean code, remove derived data, build and run.

Comment: Delete (by reference) and add Assets.xcassets again, Next clean and build the project.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I had to delete an old script that references this Asset file to be built within Derived Data. Regardless of how much I deleted Derived Data and cleared Build Folder, this script still runs the XCAssets reproducing this bug. I would recommend checking out your Build Phases and Scripts and removing unnecessary files especially for old projects.

[image: Build Phases Script]